# Problems related to Wine, ProShow Producer

Tags: wine

Over the years, I've installed on my PC different versions of Linux, from Red Hat, Mandrake, Suse and now Ubuntu. Every time I'm a bit disappointed and I've to go back to Windows, as I'm unable to run under Linux, those apps which do usually run without problems under Windows.

With Windows I've created outputs in form of files.exe, several video using Proshow Producer by "PHOTODEX". The main problem seems to be related to Wine and PlayOnLinux.

When I try to play a file.exe the file starts with soundtrack, after a while the sound disappears without reason or it happens that the file doesn't start at all and the PC crashes or freezes. I've tried many different versions of Wine but the result is always the same, I can't get the files.exe to run.

Help needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The wine tag says "Wine is a software compatibility layer that allows some Windows programs to be run on Ubuntu."

Unfortunately, it is in no way a complete replacement for Windows, so if you still want to use Linux you can try one of this alternatives:

1. look for similar software that runs natively for Linux;
2. use a virtualixation system like VirtualBox
3. use a dual boot configuration to run your native Windows applications in a true Windows environment.